# Matching strings with a space between them and joining patterns with overlapping space

Tags: c#, regex, backtracking, regex-lookarounds

In the following string:

```
G 767
```

I'm trying to match the `G` and the `767` with two patterns that I join at runtime as each of them is a separate type for which I have a separate class .

```
^(?<ServiceType>[A-Z])(?= )
```

and

```
(?<= )(?<AircraftType>[A-Z0-9]{3})(?= |$)
```

If I unit test each pattern separately with `G` and `767` they work but joined together the backtrack sends the  regex engine to the beginning of the string (tested in regex101 debugger). However it works when I put a space between the two lookarounds. I'd rather not do it if possible. It also works when I use two `? ?` instead of the lookarounds but I'm not really happy with this solution either because it would allow two spaces where only one is allowed.

How should I modify the patterns so they work for each case tested separately and also when joined together.

Why is this happening at all that after the first match the engine starts scanning at the beginning of the string? I thought it would continue after the `G` then see the space for the lookbehind and match the second string.

The plan was to create overlapping patterns and the space should be common for both of them.

Comment: How does your final regex look like? Your lookarrounds doesn't consume any char. If you combine both together the space has to match but your regex doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The final regex is just the first one + the second one. The space is matched by the lookahead and the lookbehind but only if I test them separately. Merged the pattern doesn't work like that.

Comment: Lookarrounds doesn't consume any char. You have to add it. But your first regex forces this space. Why not including it into pattern? `^(?<ServiceType>[A-Z])\s` This should work for your test and the concatenation.

Comment: Try joining with `|`: [`^(?<ServiceType>[A-Z])(?= )|(?<= )(?<AircraftType>[A-Z0-9]{3})(?= |$)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cServiceType%3e%5bA-Z%5d)(%3f%3d+)%7c(%3f%3c%3d+)(%3f%3cAircraftType%3e%5bA-Z0-9%5d%7b3%7d)(%3f%3d+%7c%24)&i=G+767).

Comment: @stribizhev this matches only the first string.

Comment: @t3chb0t: No idea what you mean, there are 2 matches, see *Table* tab on regexstorm. Anyway, I do not insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the following patterns:

`^(?<ServiceType>[A-Z])\s`
and
`(?<= )(?<AircraftType>[A-Z0-9]{3}(?= |$)`

These can be merged together with:

```
var pattern = firstPattern + secondPattern;
```

If it's not working please specifiy the exact problem.

Comment: I'd like to be able to concentrate both patterns so the space between them that each pattern already matches becomes common for both of them but I don't want to add the extra space. I had hoped the two lookarohnds would overlap over the space.

Comment: @t3chb0t I changed the answer. Hopefully it'll work now.

Comment: Actually I should accept two answers ;-) but pick up this. @vks thanks for explaining the zero width assertion. I'll go with the consuming space after the string and with a lookbehind in the next string. I have to add another few patterns so it seems to be a good compromise I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?<ServiceType>[A-Z])(?= ) +(?<= )(?<AircraftType>[A-Z0-9]{3})(?= |$)
```

You have to consume the `space` as `lookarounds` are `0 width assertions` so will not consume space.For regex engine to get an overall match the `space` has to be consumed by somebody.

Comment: Knowing this solved a few other problems that I had with subsequent patterns ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t glad it helped :)